# Ubuntu terminal automatically executes a python script. How to stop it?

Tags: python, conda

I'm using Ubuntu 19.10.

I recently installed PyTorch in the root environment of Anaconda3. After the installation, whenever I open the terminal window, a python script runs, and throws out import error "no module named conda".

I am unable to track down the file which the terminal is executing.

Here's the exact code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
ImportError: No module named conda
anubhav@anubhav-ubuntu:~$
```

I tried tacking the file down in `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` still no use of it.

How can I stop the terminal to execute the file?

Comment: To troubleshoot you could [see what files Bash is reading from on startup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/334389/117037). You could also try `bash -x`, find the error, then the line immediately above will be the direct cause of the error.

Comment: @wjandrea Using `bash -x` and `echo exit | strace bash -li |& grep '^open[a-z]*'`   as given by you, worked for troubleshooting and debugging the problem. Thanks a lot!

If possible, could you please put it up as an answer, so that I could mark it as accepted? It would greatly help others.

Comment: Done. Glad I could help btw! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To troubleshoot you could see what files Bash is reading from on startup:

```
echo exit | strace bash -li |& grep '^open[a-z]*'
```

*(From [AlexP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/198936/alexp)'s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/334389/117037) on Unix & Linux. You could remove `-l` since Bash isn't in login mode by default on Ubuntu.)*

You could also try `bash -x`, find the error, then the line immediately above will be the direct cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have more than one version of python installed and are running the current version for your application.

Comment: I have python3 and python2 installed apart from Anaconda3.
The python code which is running is not at all usable to me. I want to stop from being executed every time I open the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Type

```
$ ps -e | grep python
```

the id(s) you get, type them here

```
$ more /proc/ID/cmdline
```

to see which command started the Python process.

Comment: I'm not getting any id. Tried with both `python` and `python3`

Comment: However, `ps ax | grep python` worked. It showed me that `python` started the command.
But, I have already figured it out that, python is running a command at the startup of terminal, though I can't find out where the command is written for the terminal to execute it. I want the location so that I can remove that line to stop the execution.

Comment: @AnubhavSachan How did you solve the problem eventually?

Comment: @rainman Refer to the accepted answer.
I used those commands to find out the directory and manually check for the file to find out the code. That code was edited by me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you just upgrade or installed conda 4.8.0 rather than 4.7.12. Based on [9507](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9507), a similar issue is raised since the conda was called before your anaconda was "declared", which means that it is the system python (which did not include conda) but not anaconda was called during the initiation. And they also provide a temporary solution in "piglesias1"'s comment.